# C++ operation overloading for multiple types with variadic template initializer list

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

Hello i´ve created a simple 2D coordinate class (Point2D) and i want to overload this class with some basic operations ( + - * / ) for some basic types(short,int,double....) so i thought i should use a template. The problem is that i get some strage numbers(i think that these are the max size of the type) as x and y value back so therefore it ignores my e.g addition.

```
Point2D *p = new Point2D(5, 7) //everything works fine here x=5 y=7
Point2D *p = new Point2D(5, 7) + 10;//x= 1.09 * e^-38 same for y but it want x=15 and y=17
```

Heres the definition of my operation overloading function :

```
template<class T>
Point2D Point2D::operator+(initializer_list<T> elementList)
{
    for (auto elem : elementList)
    {
        this->x += elem;
        this->y += elem;
    }
    return Point2D(x,y);
}
```

Comment: Looks to me like you're trying to add `10` to a pointer to a `Point2D`, not to a `Point2D` itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour of

```
Point2D *p = new Point2D(5, 7) + 10;
```

is *undefined*. The right hand side is grouped as `(new Point2D(5, 7)) + 10` which is adding 10 lots of `sizeof(Point2D)` to the `Point2D*` pointer returned back from `new`!

You are not allowed to set a pointer to memory you don't own, with the exception of one past the end of an array, or one past the address of a scalar, or `nullptr`.

Comment: Thanks helped me much,

Answer (score 0):

You can't add `10` to a pointer like that. One way to fix it would be to simply create `Point2D's` as a local variable:

```
Point2D p (5, 7);
Point2D q = p + 10;
```

`q` will now equal `15,17`

That's assuming you create an `operator+` that can take `ints` - your `initializer_list` one won't work here (because `10` isn't an `initializer_list`:

```
template<class T>
Point2D Point2D::operator+(T e)
{
    x += e;
    y += e;

    return Point2D(x, y);
}
```

Comment: Its my first time i work with initializer list aren´t they supposed to work like an vector just more type safety? My error-list tells me that (int,int,int) is not a Point2D for p = *p->operator+(10, 12, 13);